# Smooth plot of coarsely spaced table values

Tags: plotting, interpolation

[image]In a simpler first case I plotted reasonably spaced (stability) contours by selecting a sequence of k values,

```
k = {.0001, .025, .055, .1, .15, .2, .25, .3, .35, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, 1., 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3, 4, 6, 8, 16}
```

and computing an analytic function at those k with a color sequence matched.

Now in a more complicated case to compare with the original at the same `k` values and colors,  the analytic function is replaced by numerical integration and asymptotic expansion.

I generated a table of the new function at those `k` values, but `ListLinePlot` of these entries vs `k` draws disjointed line segments between the table points. I just want a smooth curve with no kinks. I tried `ListCurvePathPlot` and `Interpolation Order` but they still left the kinks at the admittedly coarse last few data points. I can create a second display list with more data points to minimise the kinks, but use the original for my stability curves for comparison with my earlier case.

Would be very grateful for any suggestions of other  simple things I can try at the plot stage as I have now been stuck for several hours on this simple problem. Thank you

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far.  May be helpful to understand what you are doing ...

Comment: Also, clarify what you need exactly!!? Plotting Smooth curve as i got! Right!?

Comment: u/sdb2754 was trying to write a function that plots a cubic fit to a data set (similar to ListLinePlot, but with splines instead of lines). He had:ListSplinePlot[data_, x_] := 
 Show[ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[InterpolatingPolynomial[data, x], {x, 
    Min[Transpose[data][[1]]], Max[Transpose[data][[1]]]}], 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

That doesn't work, I have lists of 2 element lists with the first element k, no implicit x.  I don't see where he specified that the polynomial is a cubic.
Above all I don't understand why Mathematica does not have a built in ListSplinePlot

Comment: @simon Are you looking for something like `ListLinePlot[k, InterpolationOrder -> 3]`?

Comment: Could you include a complete sample data set and some code to show what you mean by colors?  Right now it's not clear at all what you are looking for.

Comment: No raisng the inerpolation order inroduces more artifacts and leaves key discontuity in slope at data points

Comment: Do you have a sense of the error size of your numerical integration? Also, an underlying structure/parameterization of the curves you are trying to pass through the points?

Comment: The tails where the kinks are most obvious are asymptotically  inverse powers of k.

Comment: Because of the numerical integration, you are getting approximate `f[k]` values and so interpolation is not the right thing to do. Instead, you should come up with parameterizations of the curve and then optimize those to fit the data. Finding the parameterization can be a mix of craft and science.

Answer (score 0):

For your k table is the same

```
k = {.0001, .025, .055, .1, .15, .2, .25, .3, .35, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8,
    1., 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3, 4, 6, 8, 16};
```

this is the curve using `ListLinePlot` or `Joined` in `ListPlot`

```
ListPlot[k, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**but you want it smooth curve!!? Here is**

**First Method**

As well you can change `n` in `FitPolynomial` or `x` in `Plot` to get more desired result.

this it the best smooth curve i get!

```
k = {0.0001, 0.025, 0.055, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 
1., 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3, 4, 6, 8, 16};

FitPolynomial[data_] := Fit[data, Table[x^n, {n, 0, 10}], x]; 
q = FitPolynomial[k]; 
p2 = Plot[q, {x, 1, 25}]

p1 = ListPlot[k]
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

**Second Method**

As well you can change order in `InterpolationOrder`

```
k = {.0001, .025, .055, .1, .15, .2, .25, .3, .35, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8,
1., 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3, 4, 6, 8, 16};


p1 = ListPlot[k]
p2 = ListPlot[k, InterpolationOrder -> 5, PlotRange -> All, 
  Joined -> True]

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: I am so sorry you misunderstood the problem,  There is no implicit x, the k's are my preselected x values. I have lists of {k,f1}, {k,f2} values etc and need each list of points to be spline plotted. I will study your answer to see if there is something there I can use